# cannot resolve R.array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I follow the tutorial from [Capturing images from camera and setting into listview in android](https://trinitytuts.com/capturing-images-from-camera-and-setting-into-listview-in-android/). However, I get

> Error:(42, 50) error: cannot find symbol variable array

```
  String imageTempName;
    String[] imageFor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.captureList);
        getSets = new ArrayList<GetSet>();
       imageFor = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.imageFor);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            GetSet inflate = new GetSet();
            // Global Values
            inflate.setUid(String.valueOf(i));

            inflate.setLabel("Image");
            inflate.setHaveImage(false);
            inflate.setSubtext(imageFor[i]);
            inflate.setStatus(true);

            getSets.add(inflate);
        }
        customImageAdapter = new CustomImageAdapter(getSets, MainActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(customImageAdapter);
    }
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: Post your resource file where you store string array

Comment: @404notfound I follow [this](https://trinitytuts.com/capturing-images-from-camera-and-setting-into-listview-in-android/)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  `imageFor = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.imageFor);`

Comment: Dear downvoters, please let me know what's I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Check your imports. Maybe you miss: `import your.package.name.R;`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein `package com.example.ongws.r;` my package name

Comment: import `com.example.ongws.r.R;` ?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein No luck...

Comment: No. **R** is upper case and has to appear only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cheched your link. This tutorial is missing array declaration -> No one array is declared in string resources - > Your error happen!

Add this to `strings.xml`

```
<string-array name="imageFor">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

Where `1`, `2` , `3` are your `strings`. In this case probably they are image urls.

Comment: Thanks, I' ve been finding this for more than half hour and you saved me ^^

Comment: ... or `arays.xml`. Or any other name you like, what what it matters.